# How to check if a process is running by name on Unix when there is no cmdline file inside the proc directory?

Tags: c, unix, qnx

So I am running on `QNX` and I want to check if a process is up and running.
I saw many examples on how to do this - basically iterate over the `proc` directory, and over and processes inside (which are some numbers - pid) and inside this there should be a `cmdfile` file.

But on my controller if I list the processes using `pidin` and get the pid for it and search it on FTP inside the `proc` folder, it doesn't contain anything, its empty.

What does this mean ? How should I check if the process is running by name ?

Here is a screenshot - `15179` is the process.

[image]

Comment: I'd guess that you don't have permissions to read /proc/151579

Comment: Hmm, is there a way I can change the persimissions ? Or is set externarlly by someone.

Comment: not on a 'standard unix' as far as I know (don't know anything about QNX). To read id you normally have to have the same uid as the process or root

Comment: ohh, yeah, logged in with root and now I can access it. Thanks, never wondered to log in with the root user

Comment: But... `ps` was not enough?

Comment: What's wrong with `ps -ef` or `pgrep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using FileZilla as I can see from the screenshot. You need to login as root user to access /proc location.

I'd recommend to SSH to the server and check the processes which are running using the ps, top or pgrep command. Using the command line provides much more options.